# Sidekiq & Clock Background Task On Redis, Rails, Heroku Only Updating Some

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, clockwork

I am running a background task on many records with Rails, Sidekiq, Redis, and Clockwork on Heroku, but I keep getting this error on many of the records it's trying to update with an API:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds
```

Here are my files:

Unicorn:

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
    config['pool']            = ENV['DB_POOL'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Database:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: production
  pool: 25
  timeout: 10000
```

Clock:

```
every(24.hours, 'Update') do
  sites = Site.order(:id).pluck(:id)
  Site.each do |site|
    UpdatePosts.perform_async(site)
  end
end
```

UpdatePosts

```
class UpdatePosts
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: false

    def perform(site_id)
    ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you checked the maximum number of connections your Postgres server supports? If you're hitting the limit, that might explain the error...

Comment: It's 20 connections. Is there a way to make it work with that or do I need to upgrade my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by more threads trying to obtain a connection from the ActiveRecord connection pool than there are connections in the pool.  When a thread asks for a connection, but one isn't free within the 5 second timeout, the error you see is raised.

In Sidekiq, there are a larger number of worker threads than the default ActiveRecord pool size.  This causes errors like this under load.

You can adjust the DB pool size to match the number of Sidekiq threads in your `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` file using code like this:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  if(database_url = ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
    pool_size = Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] + 2
    ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = "#{database_url}?pool=#{pool_size}"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Although you have attempted to increase the `pool_size` in your `database.yml` file, this configuration is overwritten on deploy in Heroku and driven entirely by the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out forever. Thank you so much.